# BufferedReader input attempt from System.in throwing exceptions

Tags: java, input, bufferedreader, inputstreamreader

I am trying to read a from the input using BufferedReader. It works the first time but the second time it is ran I get an exception.

```
john@fekete:~/devel/java/pricecalc$ java frontend.CUI 
> gsdfgd
Invalid command!
> I/O Error getting string:  java.io.IOException: Stream closed
I/O Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
> I/O Error getting string:  java.io.IOException: Stream closed
I/O Error: java.io.IOException: java.io.IOException: Stream closed
> I/O Error getting string:  java.io.IOException: Stream closed
```

It just keeps running with that in a loop. I must have missed something.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
            if (args.length == 0) {
                    while (!exit) {
                            try {
                                    exit = processLine(commandLine());
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                    System.out.println("I/O Error: " + e);
                            }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Bye!");
            } else if (args.length == 1) {
                    String line = new String(args[0]);
                    processLine(line);
            } else {
                    String line = new String(args[0]);
                    for (String np : args) {
                            line = new String(line + " " + np); 
                    }
                    processLine(line);
            }
    }

    static private String commandLine() throws IOException {
            String str = new String();
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in))) {
                    System.out.print("> ");
                    str = new String(br.readLine());
                    str = str.trim();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                    System.out.println("I/O Error getting string: "+ str + " " + e);
                    throw new IOException(e);
            }

            return str;
    }
```

It really all seems to be about commandLine() not working so I've just included that and main.

Comment: Where is exit defined?

Comment: Please post a Compilable program.

Comment: @RohitJain its Java 7

Comment: @sanbhat. It's not compilable (on Java 7)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you're closing the stream here:

```
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in)))
```

That try-with-resources statement will close the `BufferedReader` at the end of the block, which will close the `InputStreamReader`, which will close `System.in`.

You don't want to do that in this case, so just use:

```
// Deliberately not closing System.in!
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));   
try {
    ...
}
```

It's still possible that this won't quite behave as you want though, as the `BufferedReader` could potentially consume (and buffer) more data. You'd be better off creating the `BufferedReader` *once* (in the calling code) and passing it to the method.

Oh, and I suggest you get rid of this:

```
String str = new String();
```

There's no need for it at all. This would be better:

```
String str = "";
```

But even then, it's a pointless assignment. Likewise you don't need to create a new String from the one returned by `readLine()`. Just use:

```
return br.readLine().trim();
```

... within the `try` block. Also, there's no point in logging `str` within the `catch` block, as it's going to be empty - the `IOException` will only be thrown when reading the line...